# Automatically publishing maven project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, web, publish

How can I set eclipse to publish maven web projects automatically like the way we can setup regular web projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say publish I assume that you want to publish it to an embedded app server like Tomcat. I follow one of the below approaches.

**Option 1:**

1. Install m2eclipse.
2. Import the web project as a maven project.
3. Right click the project and Run as `Run on Server`.

**Option 2:**

1. Install m2eclipse.
2. Import the web project as Java project.
3. Right click -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project.
4. Right click the project and Run as `Run on Server`.

Comment: I can't see Run on server option when I tried Option1. Same with option2 after converting to maven project :(

Comment: I used a bit different approach. I created a Maven project, converted to Faceted project (right click on project, Configure-->Convert to faceted project).